# How to create an internal JarFile Object from a byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, jar, byte, inputstream

I want to check for Updates of a Program that I am currently working on and for that I download the JarFile and write it into the Computers memory.
Now I don't know how to "convert" the byte[] created during this process into
a JarFile object.

So how to convert this byte[] into a JarFile object? So I can read the file within the Jar, containing the version number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t read the file into memory.  Just read the version directly, using a [jar URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html):

```
String version;
URL versionFile = new URL("http://www.example.com/app/latestversion.jar!/com/example/app/version.txt");
try (BufferedReader versionReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(versionFile.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

    version = versionReader.readLine();
}
```

If you’re reading the version from the .jar file’s manifest, you can just use a [JarInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html) instead of a JarFile:

```
String version;
URL jarLocation = new URL("http://www.example.com/app/latestversion.jar");
try (JarInputStream jarStream = new JarInputStream(jarLocation.openStream())) {

    version = jarStream.getManifest().getMainAttributes().getValue(
        Attributes.Name.SPECIFICATION_VERSION);
}
```

Comment: I figured out that I can use a JarInputStream now but thanks for to this post others may get the hang of it :P